# D3 Label to draggable circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to use d3 to draw circle elements with labels next to them. 
I should be able to drag a circle with a label following next to it.

Any advice is appreciated. 
https://jsfiddle.net/o3yg8sq1/2/

```
const svg = d3.select('svg'),
        width = +svg.attr('width'),
        height = +svg.attr('height');

    const node = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'nodes')
        .selectAll('circle')
        .data([{1:1},{2:2}])
        .enter().append('circle')
        .attr('r', 15)
        .attr('cx', function (d, i) { return Math.random() * 100; })
        .attr('cy', function (d, i) { return Math.random() * 100; })
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on('drag', dragmove));

    svg.selectAll('.nodes')
        .append('text')
        .text(function(d){return 'test';})

    function dragmove(d) {
        d3.select(this).attr('cx', d3.event.x);
        d3.select(this).attr('cy', d3.event.y);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is D3 v3, the correct function is:

```
d3.behavior.drag()
```

Besides that, to drag the circle with the corresponding text, a better approach would be appending both `circle` and `text` to a group:

```
const node = svg.selectAll('.g')
    .data([{1:1},{2:2}])
    .enter().append('g').attr("transform", function(){
        return "translate(" + Math.random() * 100 + "," 
        + Math.random() * 100 + ")"
});

node.append("circle").attr('r', 15);

node.append('text')
    .attr("dx", 16)
    .text("test")
```

And call the drag to that group:

```
node.call(d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('drag', dragmove));

function dragmove(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(){ 
        return "translate(" + d3.event.x + "," + d3.event.y + ")"
    })
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/o3yg8sq1/4/