# Change: Add Label to Draggable Circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js

UPDATE: Looking for a way to add a label to every draggable circle using the code below. Need the text to appear slightly under the circle and to stay in the position whenever a circle is moved. Would like to keep it using D3.

---

Building on some of the work created in [here](https://bl.ocks.org/lsbardel/b1133566e01d6d45fa7d11523dcb3e70) to building something similar.

Trying to add labels (customisation on click) below every point that move whenever one of the circles is dragged. Already seen  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866798/d3-label-to-draggable-circle)  on stack overflow.

With how the data points are set out, what would be the easiest way to do it?

```
<html ng-app>
<html lang="en">
<title>Test</title>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://giottojs.org/d3-canvas-transition/0.3.6/d3-canvas-transition.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/stylesheets/style.css?q=1280549780">
</head>
<body>
<body>
  <div id="paper"></div>
  <div class="s c">
      <div id="example" class="3 c"></div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
var PrimCol = "Blue"
    SeconCol = "Black"

var example = d3.select("#example"),
    width = 368,
    height = 583,
    radius = 9,
    area = Math.PI*radius*radius,
    margin = 2*radius,
    text = '';

var shapes = ['Circle'],
    color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis),
    N = 11,  // Number of Circles
    points = d3.range(N).map(function(i) {
    return {
        type: "Circle",
        x: Math.round(Math.random() * (width - 2*margin) + margin),
        y: Math.round(Math.random() * (height - 2*margin) + margin)
    };
});

draw('svg');

function draw(type, r) {
    example.select('.paper').remove();
    var paper = example
        .append(type)
        .classed('paper', true)
        .style('stroke', '#333')
        .attr('width', width).attr('height', height).canvasResolution(r).canvas(true);

    var marks = d3.symbol().type(function (d) {return d3['symbol' + d.type];}).size(function (d) {return area;});

    // Background Information
    paper.append('rect')
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .style("stroke-width", 0)
        .style('fill', 'White')
        .style('fill-opacity', 1);

    paper
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(points)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("transform", translate)
        .attr("d", marks)
        .style("fill", PrimCol)
        .style("stroke", SeconCol)
        .style("stroke-width", '1px')
        .on("mouseenter.hover", mouseenter)
        .on("mouseleave.hover", end)
        .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", mouseenter));    

    function mouseenter () {
        d3.select(this).style('cursor', 'move');
    }

    function dragstarted () {
        d3.select(this).raise().style('stroke-width', '3px');
    }

    function dragged(d) {
        d.x = d3.event.x;
        d.y = d3.event.y;
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", translate(d));
    }

    function end() {
        var el = d3.select(this),
            d = el.datum();
        el.style('cursor', 'default').style('stroke-width', '1px');
    }

    function translate (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    }
} 
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, the algorithm would be as follows:

1. Make groups.
2. To groups attach drag and other listeners.
3. To each group add a circle and text.
4. Drag work on the entire group so circle and text will move together.

First make a group like this.

```
var groups = paper
    .selectAll(".group-drag")//selector using class
    .data(points)//attach data to selection
    .enter()
    .append("g")//add as many groups as data        
    .attr("transform", translate)//give translate to the group
    .classed("group-drag", true)//add class to the group
    .on("mouseenter.hover", mouseenter)//attach listener to the group
    .on("mouseleave.hover", end)
    .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", mouseenter));
```

Now add circle and text to the group like this:

```
    groups.append('text')
        .attr("dx", 16)
    .text(function(d){return d.type});        

    groups.append("path")
    .attr("d", marks)
    .style("fill", PrimCol)
    .style("stroke", SeconCol)
    .style("stroke-width", '1px')
```

Now the drag will work on the whole group which comprises of text and circle, so they will move together.

working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/oRnr289pEkDDCMIXNloP?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my way, with JQuery and Jquery-UI. You can set as many with circle with div 'circle' like the sample. You can set the initial position by the data-x and data-y. Or you can make your own way, there's many possibilities to manipulate the position. I also added random initial positions. Some labels are hidden and will show when hover. If you want to trigger it with click, just remove the hover in css and add click function to your jquery.

```js
$('.fixed').each(function(index) {
  $(this).css({'top' : $(this).data("y"), 'left' : $(this).data("x")});
});

$('.random').each(function(index) {
  var x =  $(window).width();
  var y = $(window).height();
  $(this).css({'top' : Math.round(Math.random() * y), 'left' : Math.round(Math.random() * x)});
});



$( ".circle" ).draggable();
```

```css
.circle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.random {
  background: #000000;
}
.circle > span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.circle > .hidden {
  display: none;
}
.circle:hover > .hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="circle fixed" data-y="200" data-x="300">
  <span class="hidden">Hidden Title Here</span>
</div>

<div class="circle fixed" data-y="10" data-x="50">
  <span>Title Here</span>
</div>

<div class="circle random">
  <span>Title Here</span>
</div>

<div class="circle random">
  <span class="hidden">Hidden Title Here</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can set as many circle just by adding divs, like my sample. **

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It certainly works but I was ideally looking to keep all the code in D3